# HttpWebRequest in c#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I am making a Get request with following code:

```
            TheRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(aURL);
            TheRequest.Method            = "GET";
            TheRequest.CookieContainer   = TheCookies;
    TheRequest.UserAgent         = GetUserAgent();
    TheRequest.KeepAlive         = false;
    TheRequest.Timeout       = 20000;
            TheRequest.ReadWriteTimeout  = 20000;
    TheRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    TheRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-us");
            TheResponse = (HttpWebResponse)TheRequest.GetResponse();
            TheResponseString = new StreamReader(TheResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII).ReadToEnd();
```

After this I take the cookies as follows:

```
string theCookieHeader = TheResponse.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie];
```

Then I process the string to be in proper cookie format and put it in cookie container to give it in next POST request. From the Response string (TheResponseString) I create the proper Post data and the cookies from cookiecontainer.

My code for POST request is as follows:

```
                  TheRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(aURL);
                  TheRequest.Method            = "POST";
                  TheRequest.CookieContainer   = TheCookies;
          TheRequest.UserAgent       = GetUserAgent();
          TheRequest.KeepAlive       = false;          
                  TheRequest.Timeout             = 20000;
                  TheRequest.ReadWriteTimeout  = 20000;
          TheRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
          TheRequest.ContentType       = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
          TheRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-us"); 
                  byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(aPostDataString);
          TheRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
          Stream oStreamOut = TheRequest.GetRequestStream();
          oStreamOut.Write(bytes,0,bytes.Length);
          oStreamOut.Close();

                  TheResponse = (HttpWebResponse)TheRequest.GetResponse();

                  TheResponseString = new StreamReader(TheResponse.GetResponseStream(),                            Encoding.ASCII).ReadToEnd();
```

Now the problem is I have two websites,they are partner websites,they have every thing same(It seems but if you doubt about anything then please tell me),but for one website it works fine and for other one it gives the response string of websites Error Page.

Please help me what to see for diagnosing the problem.

Comment: You need to provide a different cookie to the second one, it happened with me! even if the same website, but a different subdomain, sometimes you need to provide a different cookie

Comment: Well if you're getting an error, you should look at the logs from the site which fails... you should be able to see *why* you're getting an error.

Comment: @JonSkeet I think he is trying to connect to website which have no access to, btw what about Li request :) I have installed SkeetNotifier,it is so cute!

Comment: @MSakherSawan: The thing is, we'd be guessing - whereas the OP can find out for sure, if he has access to all the logs. Yes, the OP will need a different cookie for a different site - but if he's running the first code *as well* as the second, he should already be getting a fresh cookie. Note that the naming and indentation of the post helps...

Comment: Hey,I don't have access to there logs, as far as cookies are concerned I send the same set of cookies which I get in the Response of first Request(GET)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. Try to save the cookies from request, after you got the responce or even better, put this code in `finally` block. Run it once for TheRequest.Host and second time for the host of your second site. Also look if you need http or https

```
foreach (Cookie c in TheRequest.CookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri("http://" + TheRequest.Host)))
{
   TheCookies.SetCookies(new Uri("http://" + TheRequest.Host), c.Name + "=" + c.Value);
}
```

Comment: I dont know why but TheRequest.CookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri("http://" + TheRequest.Host)) doesn't return any cookie

Comment: @user1871770 are u sure it's http and not https? Did you try to follow requests with fiddler?

Comment: Yes I did, as in my question I am having two phases, can you please tell me where to put the code or try the things you told.I have cookie container as class level object.

Comment: @user1871770 surround first and second block with try/catch and put my code into finally block. I don't know what exactly you did with TheCookies, have you initialized it? Post more code

Comment: One more thing,don't get the impression that I have to jump from abc.com to xyz.com, its like abc.com to abc.com/pqr

Comment: @user1871770 it's totally different thing, you sould run my code once for **http : // abc.com** . As I said, post the whole code